# How to close navbar when clicking outside of it

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How can I edit my code so that the navbar closes when clicked outside of it but remain open if something inside of it is clicked?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-btn').on('click', function() {
  $('.nav-btn').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nav-btn').on('click', function (e) {
        
        // Stop Document to be clicked when clicked in nav.
        e.stopPropagation()

        $('.nav-btn').removeClass('active');
        var subMenu = $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu')
        if (!$(".sub-menu").is(":visible")) {
            $(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
        }
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });

    // Toggle Sub Menu and remove active when Any vacant place is clicked
    $(this).on('click', function (event) {
        $('.nav-btn').removeClass('active');
        $('.nav-btn').parent().find('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
    });

    // Prevent View close when Sub Items is clicked
    $('.sub-menu').on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation()
    })
});
```

Hi, You just need to prevent the document click when clicked on the nav item and handle some additional things as done in the above code.

You can see [Plunker example here](https://jsfiddle.net/itsanujraghuvanshi/2shdewcx/) also.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).closest('.main-nav').length === 0) {
        // Close button code
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way is by wrapping all the content inside another div (**except** the header & navbar) and using the **onclick** tag:

```
<div onclick="hideNavbar()">
     all your content goes here
</div>

function hideNavbar() {
   $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
   // getting the navbar div with jQuery  
  // and calling the function 'hide' of the Bootstrap class 'collapse'
}
```